# multiprocess twisted service

Tags: python, service, multiprocessing, twisted

I nearly read all the questions about multiprocessing with twisted but i want to know how to deploy my TCP application with twisted.application.service, i have this code to deploy my factory using service :

```
from project.application import GameServerFactory
from twisted.application import internet, service

port = 8000
factory = GameServerFactory()

application = service.Application("Game Server")
service = internet.TCPServer(port, factory)
service.setServiceParent(application)
```

but i want to use all my cores like this ( i copied it from another question ) :

```
from project.application import GameServerFactory

from os import environ
from sys import argv, executable
from socket import AF_INET
import sys

from twisted.internet import reactor

def main(fd=None):
    factory = GameServerFactory()

    if fd is None:
    # Create a new listening port and several other processes to help out.                                                                     
        port = reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
        for i in range(7):
            reactor.spawnProcess(
                    None, executable, [executable, __file__, str(port.fileno())],
                    childFDs={0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, port.fileno(): port.fileno()},
                    env=environ)
        #sys.exit()
    else:
        # Another process created the port, just start listening on it.                                                                            
        port = reactor.adoptStreamPort(fd, AF_INET, factory)

    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(argv) == 1:
        main()
    else:
        main(int(argv[1]))
```

how can i change my first code to get output like my second code example but as service and daemonized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i decided to use HAProxy infront of (n) processes of twisted.